# obtaining argument values in stacktrace/callstack

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Why can we see the values of the arguments when we look at the "Call Stack" window in Visual Studio, yet it is not possible to obtain them programmatically using say `StackTrace.GetFrame(i)`?  That seems unfair.

Or is it possible and I'm just not aware of how?

Comment: Please read the FAQ with regard to what kinds of questions are appropriate on StackOverflow and either re-word or delete your question.

Comment: From the FAQ: "(i)f your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK." 

So, seems ok to me.